# how we make persistentStoreCoordinator synchronize in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-data, icloud

I am new in objective c and I want to know how we make `persistentStoreCoordinator` `@synchronize` to make methods thread safe. It's crash, i can clearly see crash reason on sigabort
This `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.

Please provide me any link or sample where we can check `persistentStoreCoordinator` is synchronize.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```c
    -(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
  @try{
  if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return __managedObjectContext;
  }

  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
  if (coordinator != nil) {
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
  }
  return __managedObjectContext;
  }
  @catch(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Exception managedObjectContext : %@", exception);
  }
}

-(NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
  @try{
  if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return __managedObjectModel;
  }

  NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:DBNAME ofType:@"momd"];

  if([[TrackerUtility TrackerUtilityManager] getDebugMode]){
   NSLog(@"modelPath %@",modelPath);
  }

  NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
  __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
  return __managedObjectModel;
  }
  @catch(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Exception managedObjectModel : %@",exception);
  }
}

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
  @try{
  if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
  }

  NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.sqlite", DBNAME]];

  NSError *error = nil;
  __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
  NSDictionary *options = @{
                            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES
                            };
  if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

    if([[TrackerUtility TrackerUtilityManager] getDebugMode]){

      NSLog(@"persistentStoreCoordinator error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    abort();
  }

  return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
  }
  @catch(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Exception persistentStoreCoordinator : %@",exception);
  }
}

 (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
  @try{
  return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
  }
  @catch(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"Exception applicationDocumentsDirectory : %@",exception);
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding Persistent Store can take unknown amount of time. Where are you initialising your Core Data Stack?

Comment: Hi Khundragpan, It's showing on sigabort
 This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.